# Invocable Apex in Managed Package Not Returning Values

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

We have an Apex class in our managed package declared as global but it doesn't seem to be returning anything to our Flow. Used the class prior to packaging it and it worked fine (then it was Public though).

Class is just trying to use the Apex Limits class and return the getQueries value.

```
global Class getApexLimits{

    @InvocableVariable
    global List<Integer> limitslist;

    @InvocableMethod(label='Reads Apex Limits' description='Invocable class to get Apex Query and DML limits')

    global static list<Integer> limitList(list<Integer> apexlimits){
        List<Integer> limitslist = new List<Integer>();
        for(Integer limitval: apexlimits){
            limitval = Limits.getQueries();
            limitslist.add(limitval);
        }
        return limitslist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As:

> all “managed packages” that are posted on the AppExchange don’t count
>   against your system limits

(from [Everything you need to know about the NEW AppExchange](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2012/08/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-salesforce-appexchange.html)) if your managed package meets that criteria then the `Limits.getQueries()` will only count queries that are run inside the managed package. So it will return zero if all the queries in the current transaction are from outside the managed package. (But should return a non-zero value if other `@InvocableMethod` within the manged package are called in the flow.) That is the issue may be related to the separation of governor limits by managed package namespace rather than the public/global change.

By the way, the description "Invocable class to get Apex Query and DML limits" doesn't seem valid: the method returns multiple copies of the `Limits.getQueries()` limit depending on the length of the `apexlimits` list. (Presumably you are passing in a list of length of at least 1?)

Comment: This sounds like might be the issue. Are we aware of any "workarounds" that might enable the packaged Limits class to return the queries from the transactions outside of the package? Our Flows are outside the package because complex flows do not play well with managed packages. We are trying to count the queries done by those before the "101 SOQL query limits error".

Comment: @user2451 The only approach I can think of is to deliver this InvocableMethod as part of a separate [unmanaged package](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_apps.htm&type=0).

Comment: I'll have to see if can think of a different option eventually. Cannot really use Trialforce if have to do that because all the items have to be in managed package. Salesforce has cross-namespace limits, which is similar to this issue, but it doesn't appear there is any way to access those which is essentially what I'm trying to do here. In the Prod environments I'm going back to using an unmanaged class for now.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to package the flow as an XML and include it as a static resource? Then the managed package could 'install' the flow(s) as part of its initialization.  I have not done or tried this, but wonder if that's an option.