# Getting Apex Limits in Customer Org With Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, visual-workflow, governorlimits, limits

This is related to [Invocable Apex in Managed Package Not Returning Values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171609/invocable-apex-in-managed-package-not-returning-values); however I am trying to find a workaround. We have a managed packaged Apex class that uses the Salesforce Limits class to exit our unpackaged Flows before hitting SOQL limits. Problem is when its in the package its only reading the packaged limits. Since Flows are unpackaged, the counts are always zero.

So I need to have a method to get the limits that the unpackaged Flows may be hitting in our customer org. Some answers to obvious why questions:

1. Our Flows are not packaged because putting complex Flows in managed packages still does not work. We tried this years ago and got burned. Salesforce essentially acknowledges this for now. So we install the Flows manually in customer orgs.
2. For now we use an unmanaged Apex Class but we cannot use this in Trialforce. All classes must be packaged. Ultimately we'd rather not have the unmanaged class anyway. So this means we cannot install our Flows either since they are referencing an unmanaged class that is not there.
3. A Commenter suggested doing something with the Flow, but we have dozens of Flows impacted by this so not an option and not sure would resolve.

Comment: As a short term workaround so can install the Flows, is there a way to call an unmanaged class from within a managed class? I'd want to say something like "If class A exists, then go there, else stay here". Would put this in the managed class.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this by creating a managed interface, then implementing that interface in an unmanaged class. From your managed apex you can then use the Type.forName method to construct a new instance of your unmanaged interface implementation and execute the interface methods.

Comment: You can read more here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm